# Cannot take picture or choose image from gallery

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, camera, android-camera

Sorry guys, I'm very new to android and now need to create a simple camera in my android studio.

When I choose an image from gallery or take a picture, it will crashed.

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        View claims = inflater.inflate(R.layout.camera_main, container, false);
        b=(Button)claims.findViewById(R.id.btnSelectPhoto);
        b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                selectImage();
            }
        });
        return claims;
    }


    private void selectImage() {

                final CharSequence[] options = { "Take Photo", "Choose from Gallery","Cancel" };

                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Claims.this.getActivity());
                builder.setTitle("Add Photo!");
                builder.setItems(options, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
                        if (options[item].equals("Take Photo"))
                        {
                            Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                            File f = new File(android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "temp.jpg");
                            intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(f));
                            startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
                        }
                        else if (options[item].equals("Choose from Gallery"))
                        {
                            Intent intent = new   Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                            startActivityForResult(intent, 2);

                        }
                        else if (options[item].equals("Cancel")) {
                            dialog.dismiss();
                        }
                    }
                });
                builder.show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
                super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
                if (resultCode == Activity. RESULT_OK) {
                    if (requestCode == 1) {
                        File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString());
                        for (File temp : f.listFiles()) {
                            if (temp.getName().equals("temp.jpg")) {
                                f = temp;
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                        try {
                            Bitmap bitmap;
                            BitmapFactory.Options bitmapOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();

                            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(f.getAbsolutePath(),
                                    bitmapOptions);

                            viewImage.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

                            String path = android.os.Environment
                                    .getExternalStorageDirectory()
                                    + File.separator
                                    + "Phoenix" + File.separator + "default";
                            f.delete();
                            OutputStream outFile = null;
                            File file = new File(path, String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()) + ".jpg");
                            try {
                                outFile = new FileOutputStream(file);
                                bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 85, outFile);
                                outFile.flush();
                                outFile.close();
                            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            } catch (IOException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    } else if (requestCode == 2) {

                        Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
                        String[] filePath = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
                        Cursor c = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(selectedImage, filePath, null, null, null);
                        c.moveToFirst();
                        int columnIndex = c.getColumnIndex(filePath[0]);
                        String picturePath = c.getString(columnIndex);
                        c.close();
                        Bitmap thumbnail = (BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath));
                        Log.w("path of image ", picturePath + "");
                        viewImage.setImageBitmap(thumbnail);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

**LogCat Error**

```
  java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=android:fragment:0, request=2, result=-1, data=Intent { dat=content://com.sec.android.gallery3d.provider/picasa/item/5843197728949359042 (has extras) }} to activity {com.example.project.project/com.example.project.project.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3752)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3795)
```

Can someone explain to me why would this happen and how to fix it?

Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Hey John Is that code working fine for you ?

Comment: @Naveen hi..I try ur getting imej code...the app not crashed but it does't show theselected picture in the activity..

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Getting Image from Gallery.

Try the following code.Hopefully it will work

```
    public class ImageGalleryDemoActivity extends Activity {

    private static int RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE = 1;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        Button buttonLoadImage = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonLoadPicture);
        buttonLoadImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {

                Intent i = new Intent(
                        Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                        android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);

                startActivityForResult(i, RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE);
            }
        });
    }


    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE && resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {
            Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
            String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };

            Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,
                    filePathColumn, null, null, null);
            cursor.moveToFirst();

            int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
            String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
            cursor.close();

            ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgView);
            imageView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath));

        }


    }
}
```

Comment: How about taking picture?

Comment: Read the question *"Can someone explain to me why would this happen and how to fix it?"* - Don't just post a wall of code with no explanation, especially when it's not what OP is asking for

Answer (score 0):

you can using this method

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

            private static final int IMAGE_REQUEST_CODE = 1;
            private static final int CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE = 2;
            private static final String IMG_FILE_NAME = "tempImg";

            @Override
            protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

                // From Gallery 
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setType("image/*");
                intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), IMAGE_REQUEST_CODE);

                // Take a Picture
                Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

                fileUri = Uri.fromFile(GetOutputMediaFile());

                intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileUri);

                startActivityForResult(intent, CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE);

    }

    public static File GetOutputMediaFile() {

            // External sdcard location
            File mediaStorageDir = new File(
                    Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + HConstants.IMG_FILE_NAME);

            // Create the storage directory if it does not exist
            if (!mediaStorageDir.exists()) {
                if (!mediaStorageDir.mkdirs()) {

                    return null;
                }
            }

            // Create a media file name
            File mediaFile;
            mediaFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator
                    + IMG_FILE_NAME + ".jpg");

            return mediaFile;
        }

            @Override
        protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
                super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

                if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){
                    if(requestCode == IMAGE_REQUEST_CODE){
                        fileUri = data.getData();

                        Log.i(getClass().getName(), "fileUri" + fileUri);
                    }else{
                        Log.i(getClass().getName(), fileUri);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

Taking Picture

```
public class CameraDemoActivity extends Activity {
int TAKE_PHOTO_CODE = 0;
public static int count=0;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

//here,we are making a folder named picFolder to store pics taken by the camera using this application
        final String dir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES) + "/picFolder/"; 
        File newdir = new File(dir); 
        newdir.mkdirs();

    Button capture = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnCapture);
    capture.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {

            // here,counter will be incremented each time,and the picture taken by camera will be stored as 1.jpg,2.jpg and likewise.
            count++;
            String file = dir+count+".jpg";
            File newfile = new File(file);
            try {
                newfile.createNewFile();
            } catch (IOException e) {}       

            Uri outputFileUri = Uri.fromFile(newfile);

            Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE); 
            cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, outputFileUri);

            startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, TAKE_PHOTO_CODE);
        }
    });
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == TAKE_PHOTO_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        Log.d("CameraDemo", "Pic saved");


    }
}

}
```

Also add the permissions in Manifest File:

```
      <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
      <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Comment: Read the question *"Can someone explain to me why would this happen and how to fix it?"* - Don't just post a wall of code with no explanation, especially when it's not what OP is asking for